# Get a user's last login timestamp with Microsoft Graph

Tags: authentication, microsoft-graph-api

Is it possible with Microsoft Graph to get the timestamp for last login for a specific user?

Looking in the Microsoft Graph docs I can see that you can use GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/auditLogs/signIns to get the sign-in details (presumably for all users), however this appears to be a time-consuming query (and that's if it doesn't timeout).

Is it possible to do something like GET [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/auditLogs/signIns/{user-ID}](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/auditLogs/signIns/%7Buser-ID%7D)?

If anyone knows a work-around to get the equivalent information relatively quickly that'd be really helpful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The user last Sign activity can be checked from this API.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users?$select=displayName,signInActivity
```

If you want to check in beta version of graph explorer you can refer this [signInActivity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/signinactivity?view=graph-rest-beta).

If you are looking last signin to a specific apps, then you can try MS Graph List signIns with filters like.

```
/auditLogs/signIns?$filter=userId eq 'userId' AND appDisplayName eq 'Display Name'
```

Please refer this [DOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/signin-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#example-2-retrieve-the-first-10-sign-ins-to-apps-with-the-appdisplayname-that-starts-with-graph) for more info.

Hope this helps.